# get height of div angular js

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm trying to get the height of a div in angularjs, but it only returns the initial value and never updates:

```
vm.summaryHeight = $(".history-log-container").height();
console.log(vm.summaryHeight);//returns 0 and then never logs again.
```

How can I get the height of this div as it updates?

I tried this:

```
 link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
    //console.log(element.height());
    $scope.$watch(function(){
      return element.height();
    }, function(oldVal, newVal){
     //returns the initial values then nothing else
      console.log(arguments);
    })
  }
```

Comment: did you try adding a `$watch`?

Comment: When are you trying to get that height? You get the height when it changes? How it changes?

Also, could you show us your HTML?

Comment: @MB yes I tried a watch, updating my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, the value will be taken once unless you specify otherwise. Try something like;

```
$(document).resize(function(){
  // Your code here
});
```

If your window size changing affects the height of the target element then whenever the document is resized the value will be retaken. This might also work if you were to target the element rather than the document;

```
$('.history-log-container').resize(function(){
  // Your code here
});
```

But you'd have to check that out- I just usually have all my window responsive sizings within the one document resizing function.